# Trying to install pytesseract on a Python 3.7 conda environment

Tags: python, anaconda, python-3.7, python-tesseract

I'm trying to get `pytesseract` installed on my Python 3.7 conda environment. After running `conda install -c phygbu pytesseract`, I get the package installed for Python 2.7, as shown by the output of `conda list`:

```
...
pytesseract               0.2.4                    py27_0    phygbu
...
```

Running `pip3 install pytesseract` does not help either. How can I force conda or pip3 to install it for Python 3.7?

Comment: Are you sure your conda env is Python3? Because in python3 conda env, `pip` should be `pip3`. Also, I cannot find the conda package `phygbu pytesseract` you referenced...

Comment: @Novak, yes, `conda list` outputs `python version : 3.7.1.final.0`. I have no clue either as to why it installs the 2.7 version.

Comment: The phygbu package is this one: https://anaconda.org/phygbu/pytesseract/

Comment: Oh, I see. Well, I installed pytesseract with `pip`. This is what it says in my conda env when I type `conda list`:  `pytesseract  0.2.6  pypi_0  pypi`. But the thing is that I'm using python3.6.5. Maybe that's the issue. Try downgrading python version to 3.6.5 and try installing it with pip

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have no idea what caused it, but I ended up setting a new environment altogether and reinstalling everything; this time it worked properly.